# How to commit from Android Studio to GitHub?

Tags: android-studio, github

I have already made a GitHub repository for my Android Studio project. Now I want to add the changes which I have done to the code as a new commit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At `file` menu, you will see the `Settings...` option.
In the `Settings` view, you go to `Version Control`, in this menu you'll find the GitHub option, click it.
At host input you should put the URL of the repo; change the Auth Type to `Password` and put your login and pass; click to Test button, and it's all.

When you want to commit, you can go to `VCS` menu and click in `Commit` option.